# Como convertir una consulta MySQL en array dentro de un objeto, todo esto en Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, donde cada servicio, permite tener diversos formatos de entrega.

La tabla en `MySQL` es de esta forma(ejemplo simple):

```html
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+
|id|   idServicio    |   formato     |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+
|1 |     23          |    .mp3       | 
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+
|2 |     23          |    .jpg       | 
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+
|3 |     23          |    .mp4       |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+
|4 |     24          |    .mp4       | 
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+
|5 |     24          |    .avi       | 
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+
```

De momento lo que tengo es esto:

```
public function traerFormatos() {

    $consulta = DB::table('servicios')
    ->select('idServicio','formato')
    ->get();

    return array_column($consulta->toArray(), 'formato'); }
```

Resultado:

```html
[".jpg",".mp3",".mp4",".mp4",".avi"]
```

Ya que si le agrego el `groupBy('idServicio')`, sólo me trae un valor para cada idServicio, y no es lo que busco.

Lo que estoy buscando, es realizar una consulta a través de Laravel, del cual me traiga un array de todos los formatos y que a su vez, sea agrupado por el id del Servicio, es decir de esta forma:

```html
[{idServicio:"23", formato: [".mp3",".jpg",".mp4"]},{idServicio:"24", formato:[".mp4",".avi"]}]
```

Sé que debo retornar un objeto con un `array` en 'formato' (algo que no retorna en este momento), pero no sé si debo realizar una subconsulta antes y luego realizar la consulta final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inicialmente podemos considerar el uso de (*`GROUP_CONCAT`*, recomiendo investigues al respecto de dicha función) para obtener en un solo *string* todos los formatos asociados a cada id de servicio.

Con una consulta de esta forma:

```
$query = DB::table('formatos')
                ->selectRaw('idServicio, GROUP_CONCAT(formato) AS Formato')
                ->groupBy('idServicio')
                ->get();
```

Sin embargo la salida solo llegaría a esto (*lo cual no termina de ser lo esperado*):

```
[
    {
        "idServicio": 23,
        "Formato": ".mp3,.jpg,.mp4"
    },
    {
        "idServicio": 24,
        "Formato": ".mp4,.avi"
    }
]
```

Aún así podemos tomar lo anterior como base y anexar los siguientes pasos:

1. Declara un nuevo array que posteriormente llenaremos con la data con la estructura esperada

   ```
    $nuevoConjunto = [];
   ```
2. Itera la colección recién obtenida:

   ```
    foreach($query as $renglon) {
        $nuevoConjunto[$renglon->idServicio] = ["formatos" => explode(",", $renglon->Formato)];
    }
   ```

   Donde lo que hicimos fue:

   - Al array principal le damos como clave el id de cada uno de los servicios
   - Como valor de dicha clave le damos un array nuevo con el *string* de formatos recuperados indicando que cada uno de los valores se [separe en varios de ellos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

     - En este nuevo array le podemos dar una clave llamada *formatos* a los *strings* recién obtenidos
3. Podemos al final convertir este array en una colección así:

   ```
   collect($nuevoConjunto);
   ```

Donde si hacemos un *`dd()`* de dicha colección veremos una salida como esta:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#383 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
    23 => array:1 [▼
    "formatos" => array:3 [▼
        0 => ".mp3"
        1 => ".jpg"
        2 => ".mp4"
    ]
    ]
    24 => array:1 [▼
    "formatos" => array:2 [▼
        0 => ".mp4"
        1 => ".avi"
    ]
    ]
]
}
```

Comment: Me parece acertado lo que compartiste, el problema que estoy teniendo es que debo anteponer una comilla doble en el array de multimedia, es decir: [{23:{"multimedia": "[".mp3",".jpg",".mp4"]"}}], ya que en algún momento pretendo parsear estos formatos, para enlistarlos.

Comment: lo solucioné, le añadi el json_encode ... `json_encode(explode(",", $renglon->Formato))`

Comment: Puedes publicar tu solución y marcarla como aceptada si gustas, indicando que agregaste para lograr el resultado final